# Forming linq query to get table data using table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table name stored in a string. 
I want to be able to do something like this:

```
string tableName = "sometable";

var query = from m in _Context[tableName] 
            select m;
```

I am trawling the internet as I type this...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Reflection** on entities to get the required table `DbSet` and then run **LINQ** query on it

```
var data = entity.GetType().GetProperty(tableName).GetValue(entity, null);
var query = from m in data
            select m;
```

But anyways you will get it as type of object which will not give access to properties unless you cast it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your DbContext class, add a method say called Set that returns

```
public DbSet Set(string name)
{
  // you may need to fill in the namespace of your context
 return base.Set(Type.GetType(name));
}
```

query like this:

```
  using (var db = new YourDataContext())
  {

      var results = db.Set("Namespace.EntityName") .AsQueryable();

  }
```